# Running a program from network location on Windows 7 from cmd

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have to run a configuration script on a number of computers that is stored on a network location. I run CMD as administrator and then run the command which looks something like this:

```
\\server\software\......\config.exe
```

This works perfectly well on Windows Vista and Windows 8 computers with or without UAC activated but doesn't work on any of my Windows 7 computers (with and without UAC activated). I get "Access denied" when I try to run the command.

Why is this so and how can I run the command on Windows 7?

Comment: If you copy the config file locally to the machine does it work?

Comment: It is a whole environment, not just one file. If it was a single file I would have copied it locally and executed it. The file has to be run from its location on the server with a bunch of arguments.

Comment: Are you logging in as Administrator or a user which also has admin privileges. Win 7 has something called a 'Filtered Token' which can cause problems.

Comment: I log in as a user with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map network drive using `net use` command and then execute your program from the mapped network drive

e.g.,

```
c:\> net use z: \\server\software
c:\> cd /d z:\......\
z:\......\> config.exe
```